# Access method of float type from generic function in Rust

Tags: generics, rust

I try to create a generic function in Rust, that works on all float types and uses a method implemented on `f32` and `f64`:

```
use num_traits::Float;

fn foo<F: Float>( a: F, b: F ) -> F {
    return a.rem_euclid( b );
}
```

When I try to compile this code, the compiler tells me that `rem_euclid` is not defined for `F`:

```
 no method named `rem_euclid` found for type parameter `F` in the current scope
  --> src\lib.rs:54:11
   |
54 |     return a.rem_euclid( b );
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `F`
```

How can I use this method in the generic function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Euclidean modulo methods for f32/f64 is in [libcore](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/49048), and it is not in [Float trait](https://docs.rs/num-traits/latest/num_traits/float/trait.Float.html)

You can try implement your fn like this  it is syntax OK for that

```rust
trait FloatNumber {
    fn rem_euclid(self, rhs: Self) -> Self;
}

impl FloatNumber for f32 {
    fn rem_euclid(self, rhs: Self) -> Self {
         self.rem_euclid(rhs)
    }
}

impl FloatNumber for f64 {
   fn rem_euclid(self, rhs: Self) -> Self {
      self.rem_euclid(rhs)
 }
}

fn foo<T: FloatNumber>(a: T, b: T) -> T {
    return a.rem_euclid(b);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=14affd0392a6aa0309ce828781f6bdbd), so I think this function **rem_euclid** doesn't exist on Float [trait](https://docs.rs/num-traits/latest/num_traits/float/trait.Float.html).

You can create a trait that has the function you want too. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3c35ffa36b24d08323f7b81fe19bb77d)

Comment: Your second playground code seems to be wrong. Take a look at [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e9d3907b77baab8e84b0bf13d56b7f60).

Comment: This answer could be improved by pasting the code from your playground solution here. Typically links to code elsewhere is not preferred

Comment: I found a way to implement `rem_euclid` in a custom trait:
`impl MyFloat for f32 {
fn rem_euclid( &self, other: Self ) -> Self {
f32::from( *self ).rem_euclid( other )
}
}`

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the documentation for [num_traits](https://docs.rs/num-traits/latest/num_traits/float/trait.Float.html) it does not contain a function for `rem_euclid`.

Using the following should give you the same result as `rem_euclid` and works with the `num_traits` Float variable type.

```
use num_traits::Float;

fn foo<F: Float>( a: F, b: F ) -> F {
    return (a - (a / b).trunc() * b).abs();
}
```